# Unable to create HubSpot Contact entry using hubspot-api-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hubspot, hubspot-api

```
api = ::Hubspot::Crm::Contacts::BasicApi.new
api.create({firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'}.to_json, auth_names: 'hapikey')
```

The request gets executed, but the details are not visible on Hubspot contactlist, It shows empty contact without firstname, lastname and email.

Here is the response, when I fetch the details by contact_id

```
<Hubspot::Crm::Contacts::SimplePublicObjectWithAssociations:0x000055d0bc6ad2a8
 @archived=false,
 @created_at=Fri, 11 Mar 2022 12:52:44 +0000,
 @id="456501",
 @properties=
  {"createdate"=>"2022-03-11T12:52:44.492Z",
   "email"=>"",
   "firstname"=>"",
   "hs_object_id"=>"456501",
   "lastmodifieddate"=>"2022-03-11T12:53:01.375Z",
   "lastname"=>""},
 @updated_at=Fri, 11 Mar 2022 12:53:01 +0000>
```

I have configured the API key in config file properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this to update you created contact :

```rb
 basic_api = ::Hubspot::Crm::Contacts::BasicApi.new
 contact_input = ::Hubspot::Crm::Contacts::SimplePublicObjectInput.new(properties: @properties) # your properties
 basic_api.update(contact_id, contact_input, { auth_names: 'hapikey'})
```